# What kind of amplifier do I need to drive a piezo multi layer ceramic speaker

Tags: amplifier, audio

First post here, hope someone can guide me.

I would like to use this speaker:

http://www.dbunlimitedco.com/product-detail/SZ300812-1

on my Raspberry Pi. I have an PAM8403 amplifier board driving a regular speaker and it all works well. The board is like this one:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/3pcs-PAM8403-2X3W-Mini-Audio-Class-D-amplifier-board-2-5-5V-input-/181888663216

Do you think this board can drive the ceramic speaker from 1st link?
If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can find that part at [Mouser](http://www.mouser.de/Search/m_ProductDetail.aspx?DB-Unlimited%2fSZ300812-1%2f&qs=%2fha2pyFaduhaYECrvx2szEiMziAvFSZH%2fzAXaIC3mSeQ%252bqJ6e%252bBZHQ%3d%3d)

There is a datasheet there that has a bit more information.

It is rated for operation on 5V, maximum of 16V.

It doesn't have a rated impedance like a regular speaker.  Instead, the capacitance is given as 1200 nF - that's 1.2 microfarads.  At 300 Hz, that is an impedance of 440 Ohms, dropping to 44 Ohms at 3kHz.

The amplifier IC in the module you linked to mentions that operating it with no load can damage it.  I don't know how it will react to the varying impedance of your piezo speaker.

It should also be mentioned that most normal amplifiers don't like capacitive loads.

There are special amplifiers made for piezo speakers.  You might want to check on those, and see what is different from them to normal amplifiers.  Might be a better idea to use a purpose built piezo amplifier.

[You might also want to read this page from Maxim that outlines some of the issues involved in driving piezo speakers.](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4164). It goes into some detail about the capacitive nature of piezo speakers, and how they are different from normal speakers.

Answer (score 0):

- you would need an autotransformer to boost the voltage, but since no specs are given, no idea on how may milliwatts it can handle , probably <1W

edit

- using the link suggested by JRE I created the impedance plot below which appears to be almost 300 Ohm equivalent

[image]
- so there is no problem whatsoever in driving it if you have enough voltage.

- Thus to transform up in voltage and down to 4 Ohms
- n= sqrt(300/4) ~9 is the turns ratio ,
- so I would suggest a 1:10 step-up autotransformer or audio transformer with at least 1mH inductance.